# How does Django, sorl thumbnail can display images for AMP <amp-img src="{{}}...?

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm trying to display thumbnails on amp website. I changed "img" into "amp-img", then the thumbnail doesn't display.

This following code doesn't work.

```
{% thumbnail item.image "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <amp-img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}"></amp-img>
{% endthumbnail %}
```

This works.

```
{% thumbnail item.image "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

But "img" is not allowed for amp.
Is there a way to use sorl thumbnail for amp?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this won't work, since the `sorl-thumbnail` doesn't support `amp-img` tag.

To work with thumbnail with `amp-img` the best possible solution I can suggest is use `srcset`, using `srcset` would enable your browser to fetch the appropriate image size. You can read more about [srcset here](https://amp.dev/fr/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/art_direction?referrer=ampproject.org)

Comment: I could do what I want.　<amp-img src="{{ im.url }}" srcset="{{ im.url }} 60w" layout="responsive" width="30" height="30" sizes="(min-width: 30px) 4vw, 5vw"></amp-img>　Thanks a lot!!